# PHP form Submit multiple values through one form field and append to array

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, post

I have php form that posts data to URL with single field, the problem is I can only submit one value. I have a barcode scanner that I want to be able to scan multiple serial number barcodes and submit the form. I probably need a javascript but I am not sure. See below

```
<?php
   echo("Serial Number: " . $_POST['serial'] . "<br />\n");
?>

<form action="myform5.php" method="post">
   <p>First name: <input type="text" name="serial" /></p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So in other words, I want a form field where I can enter multiple serial numbers and be able to post the data to the URL. Since I am using barcode scanner which also submits enter key after each scan, so I want to be able to add multiple serials without touching the keyboard and when finished, should be able to click submit and it posts the data.

The SQL query would be something like this;

```
select * from hdds where serial IN ('5MQ3DJAA', '5MQ3DJAB', '5MQ3DJAC', '5MQ3DJAB', '5MQ3DJAR');
```

I dont want to use the textarea field, I cannot figure out how to have a single input type text field and have a add button next to it, when a serial number is scanned or entered, that number is added to list below, that number is shown below the field and serials keep adding up when done press the submit button that posts the data.

This is what I am looking to do, see below example.

[image]

I would appreciate a small working example?

Comment: a) use a textarea and split it via php to singeltons b) use more input fields and change the name to name="serial[]" so you will get an array

Comment: hpu you want to separate serial number just space or comma or other during input?

Comment: I have just add more information to the question, that may explain what exactly I want to achieve

Comment: You should probably add a javascript tag to your question, if you want to dynamically add more inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enter multiple serial numbers then add serial number as an array values. Try this :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "Serial Numbers";
        echo "<br/>";
        $serial = $_POST['submit'];
        print_r($serial);
    }
?>

<form action="myform5.php" method="post">
   <p>serial number: <input type="text" name="serial[]" /></p>
   <p>serial number: <input type="text" name="serial[]" /></p>
   <p>serial number: <input type="text" name="serial[]" /></p>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I have tested it, but it gives me only 3 inputs to enter the serial numbers, I want just one input and add button next to it, I keep entering the serials numbers, these are shown underneath. When completed I need to be able to click submit that posts the data to URL. Can you please help?

Comment: i think you are looking for this :

http://phppot.com/php/php-jquery-dynamic-textbox/

Comment: Parkash I have added more information along with picture, please take a look at it. Thanks